# Initialize BehaviourSubject with value from an Observable in an Angular template

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am using the following pattern a lot in my Angular application. I have an observable that comes from an RxJs BehaviourSubject that has to be initialised with a value from another observable. I'd like to use it in an async pipe. The only way I can achieve this is like so:

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.notificationService
        .getNotificationForOperationId(`${this.operation.operationId}`)
        .subscribe((notification: Notification) => {
            this.activitiesExists = notification?.activities;
        });
}
```

then I subscribe to changes to that variable:

```
    subscription = this.notificationService.notificationUpdated$
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.activitiesExists = true;
    });
```

I use the variable in my template:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="activitiesExists">
   ...
</ng-container>
```

I'd rather use the variable with an async pipe like so:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="activitiesExists | async">
   ...
</ng-container>
```

but I don't know how to define the variable in on RxJs statement. I am aware of the `startWith()` RxJs Operator, but it only accepts static values and not an observable.

I'd like to use something like this, but it seems it does not exist:

```
    this.activitiesExists = this.notificationService.notificationUpdated$.pipe(
        startWith(this.notificationService.getNotificationForOperationId(this.operation.operationId))
    );
```

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. When you define your behaviourSubject you have to initialize with a default which can be of any type or even "any".

Comment: I believe `concat`ing your 2 observables can work

Comment: Would a more declarative approach help? Something like covered here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2KAn50QBBw    If you could build a short stackblitz that demonstrates the issue we can look into it further and provide a more specific reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone's interested. It seems that I have figured it out :

```
        this.activitiesExist$ = this.notificationService
            .getNotificationForOperationId(this.operation.operationId)
            .pipe(
                switchMap((notification) =>
                    this.activitiesRecordingService.notificationUpdated$
                        .pipe(map((non) => non.operationId === this.operation.operationId))
                        .pipe(startWith(notification?.activities?.length > 0))
                )
            );
```

In the first step I get the current value (notifications for an operation) and immediately switchMap to updates on that value.
There I use "startWith" to initialize the observable with the result from the first observable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something more of a declarative approach like this:

```
activitiesExists$ = this.notificationService
    .getNotificationForOperationId(`${this.operation.operationId}`)
    .pipe(
      map((notification: Notification) => notification?.activities)
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. that way the second observable that listens for updates is not included.